# convert DB2 timestamp to SAS numeric

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to convert the Db2 timestamp into SAS numeric

```
proc sql;
connect to db2 ;
     create table db2ts as
     select * from connection to db2
     (select char(current timestamp)
      from sysibm.sysdummy1)
      as db2ts(timestm);

   %put &sqlxmsg ;
   %put &sqlxrc ;

  disconnect from db2;
quit;

data _NULL_;

   set DB2TS;
    
putlog 'timestmb--' timestm;

datets =input(timestm,yymmdd10.);
timets =input(substr(timestm,12),time15.);
dt2=dhms(datets,0,0,timets);
format datets date9. timets time15.6 dt2 datetime26.6;

putlog 'currdatets:' dt2;

call symput('currdatets',catx('-',put(datepart(dt2),yymmdd10.),
     translate(put(dt2,tod15.6),'.',':')));

putlog 'currdatets:' currdatets;


run;

timestmb--2022-05-18-16.44.54.587001

currdatets:18MAY2022:16:44:54.587001

%put currdatets: &currdatets;

currdatets: 2022-05-18-16.44.54.587001

Proc sql:

Insert into table1

(Time, Type)

Values

(%sysfunc(quote(&currdatets)), 'A')
```

Error:

ERROR: Value 1 of VALUES clause 1 does not match the data type of

the corresponding column in the object-item list(in the SELECT        clause).

how can I use the macro variable currdatets to insert into the DB2 table?

Comment: 1) Your first SQL does not look valid. What is the NAME of the variable that has the cast timestamp?  What is that last stuff after the DB2 code?  2) Where are you trying to convert the string that the CAST() function generated back into a number?   You would need to either use the INPUT() function or convert the string into a datetime literal.  3) Dose DB2 really insert those periods where SAS syntax expects colons in the datetime string?

Comment: db2 timestamp ll be stored in the variable "currdatets". is it possible to change the period to colon from db2 timestamp?  2022-05-17-09.51.05.529487 to 2022-05-17:09:51:05.529487

Comment: i have tried substr(timestm,11) = ':';
substr(timestm,14) = ':';
substr(timestm,17) = ':'; and getting value as "2022-05-17:  :  :"

Comment: i have updated the code, can u pls check n help?

Comment: WHy are you pulling the timestamp out of DB2 into SAS and then trying to stick it back into DB2?  Why not just do that operation in DB2 where it can handle such precision more easily?

Answer (score 0):

So your first query is not valid SQL syntax so I am not sure how it even works.  Try something like:

```
create table db2ts as
  select * from connection to db2
  (select char(current timestamp) as timestmp
   from sysibm.sysdummy1)
;
```

This will create a dataset name `db2ts` with a character variable named `timestmp`;

Which should be the similar to what you would get with this data step.

```
data db2ts ; 
  timestmp ='2022-05-17-12.02.43.387486';
run;
```

Now you can convert the string into a DATETIME value by first converting it into a DATE and a TIME value and then combining them.

```
data want ;
  set db2ts;
  date=input(timestmp,yymmdd10.);
  time=input(substr(timestmp,12),time15.);
  datetime=dhms(date,0,0,time);
  format date date9. time time15.6 datetime datetime26.6;
  put (_all_) (=/);
run;
```

Results:

```
timestmp=2022-05-17-12.02.43.387486
date=17MAY2022
time=12:02:43.387486
datetime=17MAY2022:12:02:43.387486
```

It would be easier if you could figured out if DB2 has a function, or option for the CAST() function, that can let you specify how the string is generated so that it is something that SAS can recognize immediately as a datetime.

Comment: thank you Tom, how can i pass value of datetime into insert using macro..when i used symput the micro seconds got rounded up again

Comment: Macro variable to do what?  If you want to use the value as a number of seconds in SAS code then just store the actual numeric value as a string of digits.  `call symputx('mvar',datetime);` If you want to use it in DB2 code then use something that converts it into a string that DB2 will recognize as a datetime constant. To mimic the value you received perhaps. `call symputx('mvar',catx('-',put(datepart(dt,yymmdd10.)),translate(put(dt,tod15.6),'.',':')));`.

Comment: 433           call symputx('mvar',catx('-',put(datepart(timestm,yymmdd10.)),
                                                                _________
                                                                386
                                                                76
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: i am getting above error when i used to convert the timestamp for db2

Comment: Close the DATEPART() function.  It only wants one argument.  It is the PUT() function that wants two arguments.

Comment: call symputx('mvar',catx('-',put(datepart(timestm,yymmdd10.)),translate(put(timestm,tod15.6),'.',':')));

Comment: this s wat i had used

Comment: i m getting this error now : The format $TOD was not found or could not be loaded.

Comment: You cannot use a numeric format with a character value.

Comment: thank you so much Tom, i am at the last step.. Insert is not working when I use the macro variable currdatets, i have updated the code for ur reference. could u pls advise how can i insert with the db2 timestamp ?

Comment: How are you trying to "insert" it?  Are you using explicit pass thru code? What syntax does DB2 expect for a timestamp literal?   Can you insert a timestamp value that you just type into the code?  If so then just build that text into your macro variable.

Comment: Insert into table1

(Time, Type)

Values

(%sysfunc(quote(&currdatets)), 'A')

i have tried the macro variable to insert but i m getting error "ERROR: Value 1 of VALUES clause 1 does not match the data type of

the corresponding column in the object-item list(in the SELECT clause)."

Comment: Are you running that INSERT statement on SAS side? Or as part of an EXECUTE BY DB2 statement?  Can you make it work with a hard coded timestamp? Can you get it to work using some other tool to submit SQL to DB2?

Comment: yes i m running the insert on sas.. i m getting same error when i hard coded the timestamp :(

Comment: I suspect your real issue is that SAS does not transfer datetime values to the microsecond only the millisecond.  Why do you even CARE about the micro seconds? If you need to transfer them then you need to do the processing on the DB2 side.  To pull from DB2 pull it as text.  To push to DB2 either push it as text and convert. Or use explicit pass thru so you can use a macro variable to code the timestamp literal in DB2 syntax. You appear to be asking the same question over and over without really explaining the larger context of what you are doing.