# convert timestamp into SAS macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

how to convert the timestamp into numeric value without microseconds value getting rounded up and store it in a macro variable

```
data temp;

ts='2022-05-18:10:11:12.796429';

ts1 = input(ts,anydtdtm26.);

putlog 'ts1-->' ts1;

call symput('new_ts1',ts1);

run;

%put new_ts1: &new_ts1;

ts1-->1968487872.8

new_ts1: 1968487872.8
```

Is it possible to store the actual value instead of the round value?

Comment: I suspect your real issue is that SAS does not transfer datetime values to the microsecond only the millisecond. Why do you even CARE about the micro seconds? If you need to transfer them then you need to do the processing on the DB2 side. To pull from DB2 pull it as text. To push to DB2 either push it as text and convert. Or use explicit pass thru so you can use a macro variable to code the timestamp literal in DB2 syntax. You appear to be asking the same question over and over without really explaining the larger context of what you are doing.

Comment: This question was answered already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254189/convert-db2-timestamp-to-sas-numeric

Comment: Do NOT use the ancient CALL SYMPUT() function to make macro variable unless you explicitly need to include leading and/or trailing spaces in the macro variable's value.  Use CALL SYMPUTX() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You keep asking this same question.

**Correction**

NO. It is **impossible** to store datetime (aka timestamp) values to the micro second in SAS.  The values will exceed the limits of precision for storing decimal values with fractions as floating point numbers.

You can store that large a number as an integer number of microseconds.  But not as a number of seconds with microseconds represented as fractions of a second.

Example:

```
836  data test;
837    second = '18MAY2022:10:11:12'dt + 0.796429;
838    micros = '18MAY2022:10:11:12'dt*1E6 + 796429;
839    put second= comma30.6 / micros = comma30. ;
840  run;

second=1,968,487,872.796420
micros=1,968,487,872,796,429
```

Notice how the microseconds place digit is lost when stored in number of seconds but when stored as an integer count of microseconds instead the value is still there.

NO. You cannot use the ANYDTDTM informat to convert that specific string into a datetime value with microsecond precision.  Use a different method. And store the microseconds in a separate variable from the datetime.

```
date test;
  ts='2022-05-18:10:11:12.796429';
  dt=dhms(input(ts,yymmdd10.),0,0,input(substr(ts,12),time8.));
  microseconds = input(scan(ts,-1,'.'),6.);
  format dt datetime19.  microseconds z6. ;
run;
```

[image]

NO. You cannot use implicit passthru to DB2 to move datetime values and retain the precision to the micro second.

To move the values from DB2 to SAS convert them to a string in DB2 and move the string.  You can then use a method like above to convert into an actual datetime value if you need.

To move the values back to DB2 you reverse the process and move the value as a string and use DB2 code to convert it to a DB2 timestamp value.  Or generate code to run in DB2 via explicit pass thru (perhaps by building the text of a DB2 timestamp literal into a macro variable) that will transfer the value.

So perhaps something like:

```
%let myts=%put<what ever the heck syntax works for timestamp value in DB2>;
proc sql;
 connect to db2 ... ;
 execute by db2 
   (insert into myschema.mytable (myts)
    values ( &myts. )
   )
  ;
```

You could try to build such a string be concatenating the date, time and microsecond pieces.  Make sure the use the Z format when converting the microseconds into a string so that values less than a tenth of a second will have the needed leading zeros.

So if you want to generate a string like `'2022-05-18:10:11:12.796429'` you might do this:

```
data _null_;
  set test;
  call symputx('myts',cats(
     "'",put(datepart(dt),yymmddd10.)
    ,":',put(dt,tod8.)
    ,".",put(milliseconds,z6.)
    ,"'"));
run;
```

Comment: thank u so much for responding to my earlier thread and for this thread. 

I am able to insert into DB2 if I use the converted numeric value "ts1-->1968487872.8" but the timestamp is inserted as "2022-05-18:10:11:12.80000 (rounded)", tats y i wanted to check if there is any other syntxt to convert the timestamp to numeric value without micorseconds getting rounded.

Comment: Make sure to include the decimal places when generating the macro variable.  Use PUT() to allow to specify the number of decimal places used to convert the datetime number into a string to put into the macro variable. So try something like `call symputx('ts1',put(dt,17.6));` to create the macro variable TS1 from the datetime variable DT.

Comment: i can see the decimal positions now, but i m getting the last digit as 0, other than tat it s working like expected

dt-->18MAY2022:10:11:12.796429

new_ts1: 1968487872.796420

Comment: Make sure when convert a string like '....:10:11:12.796429' into a number that you read all of the digits. If you use an informat that is too short and it does not read that last 9 then you will have a zero in that place.

Comment: You have exceeded SAS's ability to store fractional numbers with that many significant digits.  See the updated answer, including the suggestion to store the millisecond value in a separate variable.